# Angular 8 - For Loop in a formbuilder

Tags: angular

I am planning to get a form that would contains data and a slider for a whole year.

But, I don't want to type in the ts file the whole 365 input in the form builder.

That would be long and stupid as I would also need later on to listen to the period chosen by the client (it could be 50 days or 20) so I wanted to do a for loop in the form builder but I don't see how to that.

I put my code on stackblitz and commented the wrong part but cannot see what is wrong: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-ue3alt?devtoolsheight=33&file=src/app/app.component.ts

I tried to do a loop and then concatenate the string and the variable but that doesn't work.
Am I not supposed to put conditions on my formbuilder? Should I go on a template driven form for that?

```
for (let i =1; i =< 365; i++){
  this.revenueManagerForm = this.fb.group({
    recetteCible: [],
    occupancyRateJ1: [],
    "occupancyRateJ" + i + ": []",
    "priceMinJ" + i + ": []",
    "priceMaxJ" + i + ": []",
  })
}
```

Thanks

Comment: you need to use formArray

Comment: by assigning revenueManagerForm inside a loop you are assigning the same form 365 times. Looking at your stackblitz, you are using forms incorrectly by mixing template-driven forms (ngModel) with reactive forms.... you should probably go back and read the docs

Answer (score 2):

try with formArray like this in reactive form

```
export class SkillsComponent {
  skills = new FormArray([]);

  addSkill() {
    const group = new FormGroup({
      level: new FormControl(''),
      name: new FormControl('')
    });

    this.skills.push(group);
  }
}
```

```
<div *ngFor="let skill of skills.controls;">
  <ng-container [formGroup]="skill">
    <input formControlName="level" />
    <input formControlName="name" />
  </ng-container>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. Yes, i used both template driven and reactive forms since I got a slider that didn't work out on reactive form and that the data it represented didn't copy in the corresponding field below in the form. I got to work on it.
Since apparently, my two way bindings between slider and field only works in template driven form, I was thinking of only using template driven but does FormArray work in Template driven form?

Comment: I dont know @LucasClement. 
But this link has implementation of formarray in template driven forms https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/9615.
and pls give your solution below once you get for understanding